# Create flat array of individual values from rows of comma-separated values fetched from a database table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, flatten

Please help me to create an array from a field of my DB. That field has records separated by comma. Below is the illustration:

```
ID | article_title_fld         | article_tags_fld                     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | Learn PHP                 | PHP, coding, scripting               |
3  | Javascript Tutorial       | Javascript, scripting, tutorial      |
4  | Styling with CSS          | CSS, tutorial, web design            |
```

I want to collect all records in the **article_tags_fld** then put it into 1 array. Perhaps I named it **$array1**, and the print out as below:

```
Array
(
[0] => PHP
[1] => coding
[2] => scripting
[3] => Javascript
[4] => scripting
[5] => tutorial
[6] => CSS
[7] => tutorial
[8] => web design
)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$array1 = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT article_tags_fld FROM MY_TABLE");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $array1 = array_merge($array1, array_map('trim', explode(",", $row['article_tags_fld'])));
}
```

[explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) will split a string by a delimiter.

[array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) will combine two arrays.

[array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) will apply trim to all elements.

[trim](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) will remove any white space on either side of your tags.

Comment: I'd throw a `trim` into the mix as well.

Comment: I tried this, i got error msg "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\test\untitled4.php  on line 20
Array ( )"

Comment: Changed to use a while, loop, try that.

Comment: Good. Sorry about that. Be careful with `array_merge`. Now that I think about it, you may not get both copies of "tutorial" as you originally requested.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, I would [normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) the table into multiple tables first.

articles

```
article_ID | article_title_fld         |
----------------------------------------
1          | Learn PHP                 |
3          | Javascript Tutorial       |
4          | Styling with CSS          |
```

tags

```
tag_ID | tag_title_fld |
------------------------
1      | PHP           |
2      | coding        |
3      | scripting     |
4      | Javascript    |
5      | tutorial      |
6      | CSS           |
7      | web design    |
```

article_tags

```
article_ID | tag_ID |
---------------------
1          | 1      |
1          | 2      |
1          | 3      |
3          | 4      |
3          | 3      |
3          | 5      |
4          | 6      |
4          | 5      |
4          | 7      |
```

and then in the PHP

```
$array1 = array();
$result = mysql_query("
SELECT tag_title_fld
FROM tags
JOIN articles_tags USING(tag_ID)
ORDER BY article.article_ID
");
foreach($result as $row) { 
   $array1[] = $row['tag_title_fld'];
   // With count. See below for the query it goes with
   // $array2 = array();
   // $array2['tag'] = $row['tag_title_fld'];
   // $array2['count'] = $row['tag_count'];
   // $array1[] = $array2;
}
```

Of course, if you just wanted a list of the tags without duplicates, you'd use this query instead.

```
SELECT tag_title_fld
FROM tags
```

and if you wanted them with a count of how often they're used:

```
SELECT tag_title_fld, COUNT(*) AS tag_count
FROM tags
JOIN articles_tags USING(tag_ID)
GROUP BY tag_title_fld
```

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED**

you can do also this way by using **[mysql_fetch_Array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)**

```
$array1 = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT ID , article_tags_fld FROM my_table");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH)) {
    $array1[] = $row['article_tags_fld'];
    // OR 
    // $array1[] = $row[1];
}
```

**ADDED:**
in one line:

```
// use this version to behave as in your example..
$array1 = array_map('trim',explode(',',implode(',',$array1))); 

// use this version with array_unique for a non duplicate way...    
$array1 = array_unique(array_map('trim',explode(',',implode(',',$array1))));
```

**DISPLAY:**

```
 print_r( $array1 );

Array
(
    [0] => PHP
    [1] => coding
    [2] => scripting
    [3] => Javascript
    [4] => scripting
    [5] => tutorial
    [6] => CSS
    [7] => tutorial
    [8] => web design
)
```

Comment: The out put is "Array ( [0] => PHP, coding, scripting [1] => Javascript, scripting, tutorial [2] => CSS, tutorial, web design )"

Comment: Opps! sorry Sofyan! now i have understood what you want! my bad! let me change it!

Comment: Output: Array ( [0] => PHP [1] => coding [2] => scripting Javascript [3] => scripting [4] => tutorial CSS [5] => tutorial [6] => web design )


// There is should be a comma between "scripting" and "javascript" on key 2, between "tutorial" and "CSS" on key 4.

Comment: doh! ;-) updated one more time, this time i have tested it personally! ;-)

Comment: you missed the s1ngle quote on the left side "trim"

Answer (score 1):

This should output everything.

```
$pdo = new PDO( /* CONNECTION */ );
$stmt = $pdo->query( 'SELECT article_tags_fld FROM TABLENAME' );

function mapFunc( $row ){ return explode( ',', $row[ 0 ] ) }

$all = array();
foreach( array_map( 'mapFunc', $stmt->fetchAll() ) as $row )
{
   $all = array_merge( $all, $row );
}
// $all now holds all of the values.
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You should normalize your database table so that you don't have comma-separated values in your rows.
2. `mysql_` functions should no longer be used, so I'll demonstrate mysqli's object-oriented syntax.
3. If your database values are consistently comma-space separated, then `explode()` is fine.  If you might have leading or trailing spaces in your `article_tags_fld` values, then you can `TRIM()` that in your SQL.  If you might not have spaces after each comma, then you can explode the strings with `preg_split()` using a pattern like `/, */`.
4. The result set object from a mysqli query is iterable by `foreach()`, so you can safely avoid making iterated `fetch()` calls to access the column of data.
5. By pushing the exploded values with the spread operator (...), the result array will be flat.
6. If you want to remove duplicate values from the result, you can call `array_unique()` on the result array after the loop is finished.

Modernized Code: ([Full MYSQL + PHP Demo](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql80/f8983bcab8a743346bafd8154c087326/php/php8/99ec6774ff03061b7515cc7ccba47308/))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($mysqli->query("SELECT article_tags_fld FROM MY_TABLE") as $row) {
    array_push($result, ...explode(', ', $row['article_tags_fld']));
}
var_export(array_unique($result));
```