# using variables in other variables name - PHP

Tags: php

See this:

```
        $q = 'blah';
        for($k = 0; $k < count($results_array); $k++){
            $results_array_ . $k = explode(',', $results_array[$k]);
            foreach($results_array_ . $k as $key => $value){
                if (stripos($value, $q) === false) {
                unset($results_array_ . $k[$key]);
                break;
                }
            }
        }
```

On line 3 I'm simply using "$results_array_ . **$k**" and it's working just fine, but on line 6 I'm getting PHP parse errors on "unset($results_array_ . **$k**[$key])", why is this happening?

I appreciate anykind of help

---

Why I'm doing it:

I have an array named results_array:

```
var_dump($results_array):
0 => php,mysql,jquery,ruby,html,css,lamp
1 => mouse,keyboard,laptop,pad
2 => table,sofa,caption
```

and I have a $q which stands for query, I want to search in the $results_array and remove the items which has nothing to do with the query, so if I set **$q=a** then results array should be this:

```
0 => lamp
1 => keyboard,laptop,pad
3 => table,sofa,caption
```

now, I want to put the above results in each index of the results_array, at the end results_array should be:

```
0 => lamp
1 => keyboard
2 => laptop
3 => pad
4 => table
5 => sofa
6 => caption
```

Comment: Just a word of advice: if you're in a situation where you're creating a **variable name** using other variables' value - you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @N.B.: A very good rule of thumb, although of course it's not cast in stone.

Comment: I find this [mcve] to be Unclear.  Perhaps this is relevant: [Create flat array of individual values from rows of comma-separated values fetched from a database table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73550835/2943403)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer to original question

`unset` expects its argument to be a direct reference to a value, e.g. `$var` or `$array['key']`. If you want to dynamically create the argument based on other values, you 'll have to use [variable variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) syntax:

```
unset(${$results_array_ . $k[$key]});
```

This will get rid of the warning, but it still won't make the code work because it's fundamentally flawed. Line 3 which you mention reads:

```
$results_array_ . $k = explode(',', $results_array[$k]);
```

What this does is explode an array into `$k` and then concatenate `$results_array_` with `$k` and... throw away the result. You could just as easily have written

```
$k = explode(',', $results_array[$k]);
```

and it would work the same (except possibly not giving an `E_NOTICE` that `$_results_array_` does not exist).

So, it seems that you have a misunderstanding of how some PHP fundamentals work. It would be best if you asked another question that explains *what you are trying to do*, in order to determine what would be a good way of doing it.

#### Answer to current question

Let's take the steps one at a time:

1. Take the array of strings and turn each string into an array with `explode`, making an array of arrays. You can do this with [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) or a simple `foreach`.
2. "Flatten" the array of arrays into one big array. You can do this with [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) or [`array_merge_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php) (the details will be a bit different, the idea is the same).
3. Search the flattened array and filter out uninteresting elements with [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).
4. If necessary, reindex the filtered array so that it has consecutive numeric keys with [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php).

Here's code that does this, albeit a little differently (I am doing steps 1 and 2 at the same time in the first line using [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php)):

```
$array = (...);
$array = array_reduce($array, function(&$result, $item) {
    return array_merge($result, explode(',', $item));
}, array());
$array = array_filter($array, function($item) use ($string) { 
    return strpos($item, $string) !== false;
});
$result = array_values($array);
```

A version that does the same without using fancy functions:

```
// Step 1
foreach($array as &$row) {
    $row = explode(',', $row);
}
unset($row);

// Step 2
$array = call_user_func_array('array_merge_recursive', $array);

// Step 3
foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    if(strpos($v, 'a') === false) unset($array[$k]);
}

// Step 4
$array = array_values($array);
```

Comment: exactly, I'm not seeing the error anymore but also the code is not working! what's the solution to this?

Comment: @behz4d: Have a look at the updated answer (although I 'm still updating it).

Comment: thanks for the not fancy version, they were making me crazy here understanding them!

Comment: @behz4d: But they will make you good when you do understand them ;-)

Comment: another thing, add these to the array: 'control,television,television control, control television', and set the $q= 'tele co', now I need this to bring 'television control,control television' since they all got 'tele' AND 'co' in them, is this possible?

Comment: @behz4d: Yes, you will have to change the single `strpos` to a loop of `strpos` that checks if all the strings are present.

Comment: how about make the $string also an array which is exploded by spaces? isn't this better?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19541/discussion-between-behz4d-and-jon)