# change result of update_post_meta in database

Tags: php, database, wordpress

Have some issue in **WordPress** `post_meta` array its send wrong details in database so I want to change result of `update_post_meta` in database now i use below post meta:

```
update_post_meta($post_id, '_wpsc_vendors', array(19,'enabled',true,rate,30 ));
```

which generate this post-meta key and value:

```
key: _wpsc_vendors
value: a:5:{i:0;i:19;i:1;s:7:"enabled";i:2;b:1;i:3;s:4:"rate";i:4;i:30;}
```

now I want to change result value too this in database:

```
a:1:{i:19;a:2:{s:7:"enabled";s:4:"true";s:4:"rate";s:2:"30";}}
```

Comment: I'm not sure of understand. You want to directly change it in database or you want call to update_post_meta again with different parameters?

Comment: update_post_meta again with different parameters so result will be a:1:{i:19;a:2:{s:7:"enabled";s:4:"true";s:4:"rate";s:2:"30";}}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data:

```
array(19,'enabled',true,rate,30 )
```

when is [serialized](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_serialize) by WordPress is transformed to the follow:

```
a:5:{i:0;i:19;i:1;s:7:"enabled";i:2;b:1;i:3;s:4:"rate";i:4;i:30;}
```

meaning:

**a:5:** is an Array of 5 items

**i:0;i:19;** is the first element with index 0 "i:0", value integer 19

**i:1;s:7:"enabled";** if the element with index 1, string with 7 characters "enabled"

... and so on

The serialized value you want doesn't seems valid:

a:1:{i:19;a:2:{s:7:"enabled";s:4:"true";s:4:"rate";s:2:"30";}}

Maybe this will help you (tested with **serialize PHP function**):

```
$b = array('19'=>array("enabled","true","rate","30"));
echo serialize($b);

// Prints:
a:1:{i:19;a:4:{i:0;s:7:"enabled";i:1;s:4:"true";i:2;s:4:"rate";i:3;s:2:"30";}}
```

If you want store/update a value directly to the table, you can do the follow:

```
global $wpdb;
$sql = "UPDATE $wpdb->postmeta SET meta_value = '$meta_value' WHERE meta_key = '_wpsc_vendors' AND post_id = $post_id";
$wpdb->query($sql);
```

But I don't recommend store manually modified data to be consider as serialized, or save directly to postmeta table instead of use update_post_meta function.

Comment: may be there should a way to do so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746589/how-to-create-an-array-from-database please check

Comment: is there any way to remove i:0, i:1, i:2, i:3

Comment: You can get an array from that value too, using unserialize http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Comment: I think you can't remove i:0, i:1, i:2, i:3 because those index are generated by WP when store the data in DB. Even when I test a serialized value without those index the unserialize function returns that is an invalid serialized value.

Comment: can you create with this ?

Comment: Yes, you can use to serialize or unserialize the basic PHP function or the WordPress functions maybe_unserialize()

Comment: can you please please tell exactly what code i write to get that value here i ask this question http://wpquestions.com/question/edit?id=8563